# What is this numerically-generated function?

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, catalan-numbers

This question is an "outgrowth" of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4380919/ which led to a numerically-generated two-parameter function $f_b(n)$, where $b$ is the number base $2,3,4,\ldots$, and $n$ is as follows, paraphrasing the original question...

What is the number of $n$-character words consisting of $0$'s and $1$'s (and *etc* for bases greater than $2$) such that the number of $1$'s, counting from the left, is at all times greater than the number of $0$'s? When $b\gt2$, the number of $1$'s is greater than the combined number of all other digits. (Note: the original question only asked about the $b=2$ case.)

I couldn't see how to  rigorously set up the problem and derive a solution. So instead, I just programmed the problem, generating the following sequences for different bases

```
       n: 1  2  3   4   5    6    7     8      9     10      11      12
  base 2: 1, 1, 2,  3,  6,  10,  20,   35,    70,   126,    252,    462
  base 3: 1, 1, 3,  5, 15,  29,  87,  181,   543,  1181,   3543,   7941
  base 4: 1, 1, 4,  7, 28,  58, 232,  523,  2092,  4966,  19864,  48838
  base 5: 1, 1, 5,  9, 45,  97, 485, 1145,  5725, 14289,  71445, 185193
  base 6: 1, 1, 6, 11, 66, 146, 876, 2131, 12786, 32966, 197796
```

Googling those sequences immediately finds

```
  base 2: https://oeis.org/A001405
  base 3: https://oeis.org/A126087
  base 4: https://oeis.org/A128386
  base 5: https://oeis.org/A121724
  base 6: ????? (couldn't google anything for the b=6 sequence)
```

For base 2, that straightforward *oeis* answer is simply the binomial coefficient $f_2(n)=\left(n-1 \atop \lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor\right)$ (which immediately answered the original question).   But then we get entirely different mathematical functions for each different base $b$. At least I'm not seeing any sensible relationship between them.

So, the overall result is that we have our $f_b(n)$ generated in exactly one numerical way, but identified with apparently entirely unrelated mathematical functions for $b=2,3,4,5$ (and for $b=6$ I couldn't google anything). So perhaps we're looking at some new more general function, for which the already-known $b=2,3,4,5$ functions are just special cases. Anyway, that's the conjecture I'm asking about, and suggesting might be worth investigating further.

And in case it's of any interest the small **C** program is below. To generate results for base $b$ between $n_1\le n\le n_2$ run it with the three command-line arguments   **n1  n2  b**   (note that it just uses $32$-bit signed ints, so run it with $b^{n_2}\lt2^{31}$)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  int         n1 = ( argc>1? atoi(argv[1]) :    1 ),
              n2 = ( argc>2? atoi(argv[2]) :   10 ),
            base = ( argc>3? atoi(argv[3]) :    2 );
  int  n = n1;
  int ipow(), binky(), nwords=0, ichar=0, iword=0,
      isprefmax(char*,char,int), imax[99],nmax[99],nprintmax=1;
  char *itoa(), basechars[99] =
      "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#$*";
  for ( n=n1; n<=n2; n++ ) {
    nwords = ipow(base,n);  nprintmax = 1;
    for ( ichar=0; ichar<base; ichar++ ) imax[ichar] = 0;
    for ( iword=0; iword<nwords; iword++ ) {
      char *aword = itoa(iword,base,n);
      for ( ichar=0; ichar<base; ichar++ )
        if ( isprefmax(aword,basechars[ichar],base) ) imax[ichar] += 1; }
    printf("n=%2d, nwords=%8d,  #max=", n,nwords);
    for ( ichar=1; ichar<base; ichar++ )
      if ( imax[ichar] != imax[ichar-1] ) nprintmax=base;
    nmax[n] = (nprintmax==1?imax[0]:-999);
    for ( ichar=0; ichar<nprintmax; ichar++ ) printf("%6d",imax[ichar]);
    if (base==2) printf(",  (%2d,%2d)=%6d", n-1,(n-1)/2,binky(n-1,(n-1)/2));
    printf("\n");
    } /* --- end-of-for(n) --- */
    for ( n=n1; n<=n2; n++ ) printf("%d%s",nmax[n],(n<n2?", ":"\n"));
  exit(0); }

int  isprefmax ( char *a, char c, int base ) {
  int i=0, nc=0, nother=0, ichar=0;  int ismax=0;
  char basechars[99] =
      "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#$*";
  if ( a == NULL ) goto end_of_job;
  for ( i=0; a[i]!='\000'; i++ ) {
    if ( a[i] == c ) nc++; else nother++;
    if ( nother >= nc ) goto end_of_job; }
  ismax = 1;
  end_of_job: return ( ismax ); }

int ipow ( int base, int exp ) {
  int basetoexp = 1;
  while ( 1 ) {
    if ( exp&1 ) basetoexp *= base;
    exp >>= 1;
    if ( !exp ) break;
    base *= base; }
  return ( basetoexp ); }

int binky ( int n, int k ) {
  /* --- allocations and declarations --- */
  int   this_binky= (-1),               /* init for error */
        binky_max = INT_MAX/2;          /* assert binky <= binky_max */
  /* --- check args for "convergence" --- */
  if ( n<k || k<0 ) return ( -1 );      /* argument error */
  if ( n==k                             /* default=1 if n == k */
  ||   n<1 || k<1 ) return (  1 );      /* default=1 if n or k == 0 */
  /* --- recurse (in case one curse isn't enough) --- */
  this_binky = binky(n-1,k-1) + binky(n-1,k);
  if ( this_binky > binky_max ) this_binky = (-1); /* overflow check??? */
  return ( this_binky );
  } /* --- end-of-function binky() --- */

char *itoa ( int i, int base, int len ) {
  static char a[99], digits[99] = /* up to base 65 */
      "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#$*";
  int n=97;
  memset(a,'0',99);  a[98] = '\000';
  while ( 1 ) {
    a[n--] = digits[i%base];
    if ( (i/=base) < 1 ) break; }
  if ( len > 97-n ) n = 97-len;
  return ( a+n+1 ); }
/* --- end-of-file --- */
```

Comment: There's an obvious relationship between the titles of the OEIS sequences you link for bases 3 and 4, and if you look further down on the page for base 5 you'll see the corresponding entry in the "formula" section: for base $b$ the generating function appears to be $$\frac{c((b-1)x^2)}{1 - xc((b-1)x^2)} = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4(b-1)x^2}}{2(b-1)x^2 - x + x\sqrt{1-4(b-1)x^2}}$$

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, I guess it's maybe not as interesting a relationship as I'd originally thought. (P.S. what's that "losing confidence" stuff in your profile about?)

Comment: The "base 2" case are called "Dyck path prefixes": see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1709.

Comment: The stuff in my profile relates to a series of bad decisions by Stack Exchange (the company) made far worse by their handling of the community response. The "Monica incident" was the most notable. I've been boycotting the SE network since about Christmas 2019, but I except MO from the boycott because it's run by a separate foundation.

Comment: A perhaps more interesting/fruitful way to extend the problem to more than $2$ letters would be: words in $1,2,...,n$ such that for every prefix, $\#$ of $1$'s is greater than $\#$ of $2$'s is greater than $\#$ of $3$'s etc. With the further restriction that the number of each letter is the same, then you're looking at Standard Young Tableaux of rectangular shape (i.e., "multi-dimensional Catalan numbers").

Comment: @SamHopkins: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_word ?

Comment: @SamHopkins Sure!!!... Dyck paths, now that I look at your refernce (also https://math.mit.edu/~apost/courses/18.204-2016/18.204_Gabriella_Baracchini_final_paper.pdf and a million other google hits). And also Max's Lattice words. Wonder if the poster of the original https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4380919/ question knew any of that. I certainly didn't, but it somehow seemed interesting enough to pursue. And it seems lots of people have already done that under various different rubrics. Even, as Max points out, for "more than 2 letters". Thanks, everybody, for the elaborations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we notice that the first character must be 1. Let's take it off and focus on the remaining $n-1$ characters, where the number of 1's in each prefix must be at least as many as the number of the other $b-1$ digits.

Replacing each 1 with `[` and each other digit with `]`, we get a truncated [Dyck word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language), where a few `]]...]` at the end are truncated. The number of such words with $n-1-k$ `[` and $k$ `]` equals
$\frac{n-2k}{n}\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{k} - 2\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. It remains to distribute $b-1$ digits $\ne 1$ among the $k$ positions, resulting in the formula:
\begin{split}
f_b(n) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \frac{n-2k}{n}\binom{n}{k} (b-1)^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \left( \binom{n}{k} - 2\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right) (b-1)^k.
\end{split}

I doubt there is a simple expression for $b>2$, but the generating function can be derived from here.

Comment: Thanks, Max. I guess that's as good as it can get. Hope the question was at least worth asking in the first place. And thanks for taking the time to figure out the answer.